# Can't open/close anymore the scene collection

Tags: scene, collections

Suddenly I can't open/close the drop down arrow of the scene collection, I could use numpad "-" to close them once and that's it. Now they are closed...I can't use "+" to open them...before I was able to do both easily with the left click of the mouse (left is my preferred choise) [image]

Comment: Try to load factory settings, looks like you reassign keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: yes that's exactly the problem!. thank you so much now it's working properly